# Using Homestead for both MySQL and PgSQL

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, homestead

I am using Laravel Homestead for PostgreSQL based project. I want to use same box for another Laravel project but using MySQL. How can I mention different database engines?

Comment: `config/database.php`

Comment: I am asking how will vagrant know about mySQL?